# Backup 2 specific directories with duplicity

Tags: duplicity

I used to backup directory `/home/user/X` with duplicity using

```
duplicity /home/user/X/ file:///home/user/Backup/
```

Now, I want to backup directories `/home/user/X/` **and** `/home/user/Y/` and ignore ANYTHING else under `/home/user/` (other directories, hidden files in /home/user/)

Which is the appropriate way to specify this? Intuitively i would use

```
duplicity --include /home/user/X/ --include /home/user/Y/ --exclude '**' file:///home/user/Backup/
```

but it throws an error (`Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 1`).

I used `duplicity /home/user/ --include /home/user/X/ --include /home/user/Y/ --exclude '**' file:///home/user/Backup/`

but it produces a 10GB incremental backup for a 300MB delta file

When I use the --dry-run I get a note of

```
RawDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 0 (0 bytes)
Errors 0
```

Is there something that I am missing or mis-specifying in the duplicity syntax? Why does --dry-run show 0 Delta size while why I run the command I get at least 10Gb of incrementals? Is it because I am adding a new directory than produces these large incrementals?

PS. I am also using the --allow-source-mismatch switch

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 1

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why as I am not at my computer at the moment, but for my backup, I use

```
    --exclude '**' / file:...
```

You seem to be missing the slash arg.

Comment: Ah... After looking at the man page, I see that the slash is telling it what to backup, so you haven't told it to back up anything.